# Why am I getting this undefined method error with Ruby and Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am making a web scraper just so I can learn how. When I run it in Terminal, I am getting an error message that states:

scraper.rb:23:in 'item_container': undefined method 'css' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Here is my code in scraper.rb

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'Nokogiri'

class Scraper

  attr_accessor :parse_page

  def initialize
    doc = HTTParty.get("http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-nikeid-lifestyle-shoes/1k9Z7puZoneZoi3")
    @parse_page ||= Nokogiri::HTML(doc) #memoized @parse_page so it only gets assigned once.
  end

  def get_names
    names = item_container.css(".product-name").css("p").children.map { |name| name.text }.compact
  end

  def get_prices
    prices = item_container.css(".product-price").css("span.local").children.map { |price| price.text }.compact
  end

  private
  def item_container
    parse_page.css(".grid-item-info")
  end

  scraper = Scraper.new
  names = scraper.get_names
  prices = scraper.get_prices

  (0...prices.size).each do |index|
    puts "- - - index: #{index + 1} - - -"
    puts "Name: #{names[index]} | Price: #{prices[index]}"
  end
end
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you'll need to lowercase the values passed to `require`. After doing that, this code worked for me.

Comment: I just did as you recommended. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: That's exactly what I've got, also Ruby 2.3.1. Which version of Nokogiri do you have installed?

Comment: I'm using Nokogiri 1.6.8. Is it possible that you're being rate-limited by nike.com and not getting back the response body you're code is expecting?

Comment: pasted your code into a console and it worked just fine.

Comment: I thought about that and highly suspected that might be the case, and tried it on a different site but I get the same error there too.

Comment: There must be my something off with my system then.

Comment: Yep, my local dev environment seems to be broken. This sucks. Well, thanks for letting me know that it's not the code. I would have been at this all day otherwise.

Comment: Your code is very awkward. You need to dig into the HTML and find the parent node for the data you want. Once there extracting will flow cleanly. Also, it's also important to understand that scraping violates the TOS for most commercial sites, so you run a risk of being banned, receiving a cease and desist notice, or being sued. How to be an good network citizen, and/or avoid those things are entirely different questions. The first _might_ be on-topic whereas the second would be off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged as [ruby-on-rails]. If it's part of a Rails project then you just need to put httparty and nokogiri in your Gemfile and there is no need to require.

This worked for me inside of a Rails project (lib/scraper.rb):

```
class Scraper

  attr_accessor :parse_page

  def initialize
    doc = HTTParty.get("http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-nikeid-lifestyle-shoes/1k9Z7puZoneZoi3")
    @parse_page ||= Nokogiri::HTML(doc) #memoized @parse_page so it only gets assigned once.
  end

  def get_names
    names = item_container.css(".product-name").css("p").children.map { |name| name.text }.compact
  end

  def get_prices
    prices = item_container.css(".product-price").css("span.local").children.map { |price| price.text }.compact
  end

  private

  def item_container
    parse_page.css(".grid-item-info")
  end

end
```

Comment: It is part of a rails project. I just tried it without the require and got uninitialized constant errors in addition to the previous error, so I guess it is necessary.

Comment: Be sure to add the gems to your Gemfile and run bundle install.

Comment: I have them added in the Gemfile, and have run bundle install.

Comment: If you're getting uninitialized constant errors after including the gems in the Gemfile and running `bundle install` then the only thing I can think of is that you need to reload the environment. If you're in console, exit out and go back in. And I mean rails console, not an irb session.

Comment: I have exited out and gone back in, a few times actually. The only way that I don't get the uninitialized constant errors is with the requires in the scraper file.

Comment: However I have now  discovered that my local dev environment has, for lack of a better word, broken. And I'll have to figure out what exactly broke, fix that if I can then try this again later.

Answer (score 0):

Mediate on this:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'nokogiri'

class Scraper

  attr_accessor :parse_page
  attr_reader :url

  def initialize(url)
    @url ||= url
    @parse_page ||= Nokogiri::HTML(HTTParty.get(url))
  end

  def names_and_prices
    @parse_page.search('div.product-name').map{ |shoe|
      shoe_parent = shoe.parent
      name = shoe_parent.at('p.product-display-name').text

      product_prices = shoe_parent.at('div.prices')
      override_price = product_prices.at('span.overridden').text
      price = product_prices.at('span.local').text

      {
        name: name,
        price: price,
        override_price: override_price
      }
    }
  end

end

scraper = Scraper.new('http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-nikeid-lifestyle-shoes/1k9Z7puZoneZoi3')

scraper.names_and_prices.each_with_index do |shoe, index|
  puts "#{index + 1}: Name: #{shoe[:name]} | Price: #{shoe[:price]} | Override price: #{shoe[:override_price]}"
end
```

Which results in output like this:

```
1: Name: Nike Sock Dart iD | Price: $170 | Override price:
2: Name: Nike Air Max 1 Ultra Flyknit iD | Price: $200 | Override price:
3: Name: Nike Air Max 1 Premium iD | Price: $175 | Override price:
4: Name: Nike Air Max 90 Premium iD | Price: $175 | Override price:
5: Name: Nike Air Force 1 High Premium iD | Price: $175 | Override price:
6: Name: Nike Air Force 1 Mid Premium iD | Price: $170 | Override price:
...
```

`scraper.names_and_prices` returns an array-of-hashes which looks like:

```
[
  [0] {
    :name           => "Nike Sock Dart iD",
    :price          => "$170",
    :override_price => ""
  },
  [1] {
    :name           => "Nike Air Max 1 Ultra Flyknit iD",
    :price          => "$200",
    :override_price => ""
  }
]
```

When scraping, you need to dig into the HTML to find the best landmarks in the markup that allow you to quickly find your desired content. `div.product-name` is actually one level deeper than I'd want, so `shoe.parent` backs up one level to the parent node that contains the desired information. The result is the code is able to cleanly retrieve the information for each shoe. Using `.grid-item-info` to navigate resulted in at least one false-positive along with an attending set of nils for the inner selectors.